# Why does every project requires a specific node/ npm version?

Tags: node.js, npm, version

Why do I have to care about npm/node version (running on machine/needed by project)?

- Why does every project require a specific node/ npm version?
- Where in the project is the required version noted (*package-lock.json*)?
- Is something bad about requiring older version of node/npm?
- Is it possible/necessary to upgrade project to run with latest versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I have to care about npm/ node version ( running on machine /
> needed by project )?

This question is very broad, I will try to answer it as precise as possible. Every version has certain addition/modifications/deletions in its modules. If you have a project that runs on Nodev16 it is also important to update the npm version(some minimum version) for compatibility with peer dependencies is important. Similarly, if we have a lower node version like v12, all the dependencies should be compatible with it like npm(to install dependencies with the same version)

> Why does every project requires a specific node/ npm version ?

It depends on the project that you create. You can also update the versions of your project. There is a [guide](https://nodejs.dev/learn/update-all-the-nodejs-dependencies-to-their-latest-version) on how to update Node.js projects.

> Is something bad about requiring an older version of node/ npm ?
> Is it possible/ necessary to upgrade the project to run with the latest
> versions?

Yes, you need to always update the older version to the current version because your project might be vulnerable to security loopholes or older version compatibility issues with a newer version.

Comment: the guide describes how to update project dependencies to latest versions, this will not make the project run on latest node lts.

Comment: Once you update the dependencies, you can also update the node version.